# (ngx-openlayers) - display tooltip when hover on linestring

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, openlayers

Instead of assigning a name to each linestring as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sCF3.jpg), I am trying to display a tooltip when the user hovers on the string. I am currently using ngx-openlayers to display the name of the line.

```js
  lines : Array<{ a: number; b: number; c: number;d: number;id: string;name: string, width: number}> = 
  [
      {a:11.5820,b:48.1351,c:13.388866,d:52.517071,id:"line-1",name:"line-1", width:19}
  ];
```

```html
        <aol-feature *ngFor="let l of lines" [id]="l.id">  
          <aol-geometry-linestring >
            <aol-collection-coordinates
                [coordinates]="[[l.a, l.b],[l.c, l.d]]"
                [srid]="'EPSG:4326'">
            </aol-collection-coordinates>
        </aol-geometry-linestring>
        <aol-style>
            <aol-style-stroke [width]="l.width" [color]="'yellow'"></aol-style-stroke>
            <aol-style-text [text]="l.id" [rotation]="'5'" [textBaseLine]="'middle'" [textAlign]="'center'"></aol-style-text>
        </aol-style>
        </aol-feature>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: i managed to get the ID of the line according to what i assigned. Now i would like to have a tooltip on the feature everytime user hovers to the linestring.

```
displayTooltip(evt) {
console.log(evt);
const map = evt.map;
const p = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
 function(feature, layer) {
  console.log("got feature" + feature.getId());
  return feature;

});
```

}

Attach here is the link of what i have done https://angular-npbcjc.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error ? if not then better you create the stackblitz demo get the solution quicker.

Comment: i didnt get any error yet. it is just that i dont get the idea on how to implement this feature which is to hover on the linestring.

Comment: ok, create the demo link what you have done so far.

Comment: here is the link https://angular-npbcjc.stackblitz.io